# Filter by a class that has null properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a method in my repository to get a list, this method has a class like this:

```
Public Class FilterDTO{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime InitDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

to do the query, but NOT always all the properties have values, if I want to filter by dates I send the values for the DateTime properties, but if I want to filter by City I only send the City property, so sometimes some properties are null and the query does not return anything, this is my method in the repository:

```
public async Task<List<ListUser>> getListUserByFilter(FilterDTO filter)
{
    var listUsers = await _context.ListUser.Where(lu => lu.UserId == filter.UserId
                    && lu.City == filter.City
                    && lu.Country == filter.Country
    ).ToListAsync();
    return listUsers;
}
```

[image: PropertiesInClass]

in my database there are 9 registers with this City, Country and UserId, but the query does not return anything because others properties are null I think, so my question is how can I do the query to return these 9 registers.

Comment: Have you tried to Include City, Country and such?

Comment: Mind that `DateTime` cannot be null. You would need `DateTime?`.

Comment: You can split the expression, so you have an `IQuerable`. Then you can do things like `if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.City)) { query = query.Where( lu => lu.City == filter.City ); } ...`

Comment: @Fildor I only have to put "?" after DateTime ?, but if I want to get by dates other properties will be null, so the query will work ?

Comment: No, that's not it. As is, if you do a `new FilterDTO()` , it will have its DateTime properties set to [`default(DateTime)`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eiPwcH), _not_ `null`. So, if you query with those, you end up with a query like " WHERE Start >= X AND End <= X " , which will probably not be correct. So you need `DateTime?` to distinguish "no value", so can omit that part of the where-clause.

Comment: @Fildor ok, i'm gonna try it, thanks a million bro !!

Comment: @Fildor I finally do the query with the IQueryable doing all the validations, but how can i execute tgis IQueryable ? I have never worked with it

Comment: You "execute" it by materializing. That is: calling one of the "ToList()" or "ToArray()" etc methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a clause to check if the filter field is null before checking if each record matches the specific filter.

For the DateTime fields though, you'll need to make them nullable by changing their type from DateTime to DateTime?, like this:

```
public class FilterDTO{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InitDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, for the null checks, you can do something like this:

```
public async Task<List<ListUser>> getListUserByFilter(FilterDTO filter)
{
    var listUsers = await _context.ListUser
        .Where(lu => !filter.InitDate.HasValue || lu.CreationDate >= filter.InitDate.Value)
        .Where(lu => !filter.EndDate.HasValue || lu.CreationDate <= filter.EndDate.Value)
        .Where(lu => filter.UserId is null || lu.UserId == filter.UserId)
        .Where(lu => filter.City is null || lu.City == filter.City)
        .Where(lu => filter.Country is null || lu.Country == filter.Country)
        .ToListAsync();
    return listUsers;
}
```

The null check must come before the equality check, and using an OR (||) between them ensures that in the null case the second condition (the actual filter) will be ignored.

P.S. Chaining multiple .Where(...) calls together makes it so that they behave as AND (&&) in the final query, and, in my humble opinion, makes it much easier on the eyes for reading it :)

Comment: Mind that for this to work you need to go from `DateTime` to `DateTime?`. A `DateTime` property _cannot_ be `null`.

Comment: @Fildor You're absolutely correct. Thank you. I've updated the answer to make it correct :)

Comment: @GabrielCascaes it did not work for me :(

Comment: @AndresGuillenHernandez Do you mind sharing more details about how you tested it and the result you got? Any errors? Maybe update the question with the updated code and updated outcome?